# Msg 248, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 The conversion of the varchar value '60811404740101-60811404740102' overflowed an int column

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am getting errors with the following stored procedure. I'd like to say that I am new to SQL and currently not up to par yet but anyway, here is the values I'm passing:

```
USE [AFCache]
GO

DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC @return_value = [dbo].[csp_WellTestValidationResults_GetData]
                        @ColumnName = N'API14-2',
                        @ColumnValue = N'60811404740101-60811404740102'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
GO
```

and here is the actual stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[csp_WellTestValidationResults_GetData]
    -- Declare variables that will get data passed from PIAF to query data
    (@ColumnName varchar(max) = 'Blank',
     @ColumnValue varchar(max) = 'Blank')
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF (@ColumnName = 'API14-2')
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @APIStrip varchar(max);
        SET @APIStrip = SUBSTRING(@ColumnName, 0, CHARINDEX('-   ', @ColumnName, 0));

        DECLARE @LeftNumber varchar(max);
        SET @LeftNumber = SUBSTRING(@ColumnValue, 0, CHARINDEX('-', @ColumnValue, 0));

        DECLARE @RightNumber varchar(max)
        SET @RightNumber = SUBSTRING(@ColumnValue, CHARINDEX('-', @ColumnValue, 0) + 1, LEN(@ColumnValue));

        EXEC('Select * from dbo.SSIS_RTRM_WellTestValidationResults where '+@APIStrip+' = '+@LeftNumber+' OR '+@APIStrip+' = '+@RightNumber+' order by TestDate Desc') 
    END

    IF (@ColumnName = 'API14')
    BEGIN
        EXEC('Select * from dbo.SSIS_RTRM_WellTestValidationResults where '+@ColumnName+' = '''+@ColumnValue+''' order by AssetName, ReservoirName, API14, TestDate Desc')
    END 

    IF (@ColumnName <>'AssetName') or (@ColumnName <>'ReservoirName') or   (@ColumnName <>'FieldName') 
    BEGIN
        EXEC('Select wtvv.* from dbo.SSIS_RTRM_WellTestValidationResults wtvv join  '+'(select WellId, Max(TestDate) AS TestDate from dbo.SSIS_RTRM_WellTestValidationResults wtv group by WellId)'+' wtvv1 on wtvv1.WellId = wtvv.WellId and wtvv1.TestDate = wtvv.TestDate where '+@ColumnName+' = '''+@ColumnValue+''' order by AssetName, ReservoirName, API14')
    END

    IF (@ColumnName <>'AssetName') or (@ColumnName <>'ReservoirName') or   (@ColumnName<> 'FieldName')or (@ColumnName <>'API14-2')or (@ColumnName <>'API')
    BEGIN
        SELECT * 
        FROM dbo.SSIS_RTRM_WellTestValidationResults 
        WHERE WellId = ''
    END
END
```

When I execute the query I keep getting the following error:

> Msg 248, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The conversion of the varchar value '60811404740101-60811404740102' overflowed an int column.

I have gone through the code and I don’t understand where is my problem and why am I getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your table schema I can only presume your using a standard `int` data type for `API14` column. Looking at your code your splitting the large number on the dash (-). This is leaving you with the number `60,811,404,740,101` and `60,811,404,740,102` for the left and right sides. This far exceeds the max `int` value of `2,147,483,647`. You will need to update your column data type to be `bigint` which has a max value of `9,223,372,036,854,775,807`

Comment: Yes, I am passing 2 values that are separated by a dash, then parsing out the left and right of the dash then running the remaining of the code to query based upon the left and right values that  I parsed out. If I change the @columevalue to a type bigint, how will it hand the dash?  I must have the dash in order to parse out the numbers passed.

Comment: The error is with the column `API14`'s data type. Not the variable. The variable is already a 'varcahr(max)' which holds the large number fine. It is when you split the number and try to insert the number into `API14` that it is failing since the number is to large for the `int` data type. Changing the data type will not impact the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the `SSIS_RTRM_WellTestValidationResults` table has an int column for `API14-2`.  It would help if you posted your table schema as well.

Comment: The that table does not have a API14-2 column.  I actually strip out the -2 in the code so it is not used in the query.  The column API14 has is a varchar(max).

Comment: You need to post your table schema.  Something is not matching up the way you say it is.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing this line:

```
DECLARE @return_value int
```

With this:

```
DECLARE @return_value [numeric](18, 0)
```